# How To Detect Firefox Notifications "Blocked Temporarily"

Tags: firefox

The Firefox browser notifications dialog has a "Not Now" option which allows the user to say no just for that session

[image]

**Is there a way to detect if the user has selected that option?**
I would like to hide a button if they do

If I use Notification.permission, it returns 'default'
Which indicates that the dialog COULD be opened using Notification.requestPermission
But that does not work because it is "Blocked Temporarily"

[image]